# WinRT DatePicker Format DD-MM-YYYY XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, date, datepicker, windows-runtime

I've got a small issue with WinRT (Windows 8) DatePicker. This DatePicker consists of 3 comboboxes for Days, Months and Years. For some reason on different devices these comboboxes are being populated differently, sometimes its DD-MM-YYYY and sometimes MM-DD-YYYY.

I've tried to find a property to always set it as DD-MM-YYYY but there seem to be noting of this sort.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this? Thanks

Here's my XAML

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DateSelector" Style="{StaticResource Style.Custom-DatePicker}" 
                            Date="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            MinYear="{Binding MinimumYear}" MaxYear="{Binding MaxYear}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but have you tried what is suggested [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/346685/How-to-Display-DatePicker-in-different-format)?

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DateOfBirth,StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy'}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately that suggestion is for WPF. My issue is on WinRT (Windows 8) and WinRT's DatePicker does not support 'SelectedDate' property.

Comment: @ChristianAgius: i'm not familiar with WinRt but have you tried that syntax? So something like `Date="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy'}"`.

Comment: I did, but Date does not support StringFormat :( .. WinRT is quite restrictive compared to WPF

Comment: @ChristianAgius: have a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/africaapps/archive/2013/06/05/windows-8-getting-stringformat-functionality.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<Datepicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy a\\t h:mm tt}'}" />StringFormat=’MM/dd/yy’ : “04/17/04”
```

Comment: Unfortunately your answer is the same as the previous comment, which is for WPF and not for WinRT (Windows 8 apps).